# Compare Route Value with Request.FilePath

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC application. There are Menu items, and I want to compare clicked menu item route value with Request.FilePath to detect are they equals. But menu item's route value is.

```
/Product/it/Statue-1?deleteSession=True
```

and Request.FilePath is

```
/Product/it/Statue-1
```

How can I do it?

Comment: `FirstOne.StartsWith(SecondOne)`

Comment: Do you want to consider "?deleteSession=True" while comparing????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Request.Url.PathAndQuery` instead of `Request.FilePath` to get full path and query string.